# create combobox programmatically in ribbon visual basic

Tags: combobox, ribbon

I need to create a few comboboxes in a Ribbon based in an user´s input and then load some items, so I have to do it programatically. (VB)

I tried something like this:

```
dim myCombobox as new ComboBox()
```

But it doesn't work.Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: To clarify, are you creating something in the Excel Menu ribbon or do you mean in a userform?

Comment: I am creating a outlook Add-in Ribbon. VSTO project in Visual Studio